# (Nested?) Select statement with MAX and WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, select, join, nested, max

I'm cranking my head on a set of data in order to generate a report from a Oracle DB.

Data are in two tables:

1. **SUPPLY**
2. **DEVICE**

There is only one column that links the two tables:

- *SUPPLY.DEVICE_ID*
- *DEVICE.ID*

In SUPPLY, there are these data: (Markdown is not working well. it's supposed to show a table)

```
| DEVICE_ID     | COLOR_TYPE    | SERIAL        | UNINSTALL_DATE        |
|-----------    |------------   |-------------- |---------------------  |
| 1232          | 1             | CAP857496     | 08/11/2016,19:10:50   |
| 5263          | 2             | CAP57421      | 07/11/2016,11:20:00   |
| 758           | 3             | CBO753421869  | 07/11/2016,04:25:00   |
| 758           | 4             | CC9876543     | 06/11/2016,11:40:00   |
| 8575          | 4             | CVF75421      | 05/11/2016,23:59:00   |
| 758           | 4             | CAP67543      | 30/09/2016,11:00:00   |
```

In DEVICE, there are columns that I've to select all (more or less), but each row is unique.

What i need to achieve is: 
for each SUPPLY.DEVICE_ID and SUPPLY.COLOR_TYPE, I need the most recent ROW -> MAX(UNINSTALL_DATE)

JOINED with 
more or less all the columns in DEVICE.

At the end I should have something like this:

```
| ACCOUNT_CODE  | MODEL     | DEVICE.SERIAL     | DEVICE_ID     | COLOR_TYPE    | SUPPLY.SERIAL     | UNINSTALL_DATE        |
|-------------- |-------    |---------------    |-----------    |------------   |---------------    |---------------------  |
| BUSTO         | MS410     | LM753             | 1232          | 1             | CAP857496         | 08/11/2016,19:10:50   |
| MACCHI        | MX310     | XC876             | 5263          | 2             | CAP57421          | 07/11/2016,11:20:00   |
| ASL_COMO      | MX711     | AB123             | 758           | 3             | CBO753421869      | 07/11/2016,04:25:00   |
| ASL_COMO      | MX711     | AB123             | 758           | 4             | CC9876543         | 06/11/2016,11:40:00   |
| ASL_VARESE    | X950      | DE8745            | 8575          | 4             | CVF75421          | 05/11/2016,23:59:00   |
```

So far, using a nested select like:

```
SELECT DEVICE_ID,COLOR_TYPE,SERIAL,UNINSTALL_DATE FROM 
(SELECT SELECT DEVICE_ID,COLOR_TYPE,SERIAL,UNINSTALL_DATE 
FROM SUPPLY WHERE DEVICE_ID = '123456' ORDER BY UNINSTALL_DATE DESC) 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

I managed to get the highest value on the UNISTALL_DATE column after trying 
 `MAX(UNISTALL_DATE) or HIGHEST(UNISTALL_DATE)`.

I tried also:

```
SELECT SUPPLY.DEVICE_ID, SUPPLY.COLOR_TYPE, .... 
FROM SUPPLY,DEVICE WHERE SUPPLY.DEVICE_ID = DEVICE.ID
```

and it works, but gives me ALL the items, basically it's a merge of the two tables.
When I try to narrow the data selected, i get errors or a empty result.

I'm starting to wonder that it's not possible to obtain this data and i'm starting to export the data in excel and work from there, but I wish someone can help me before giving up...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> for each SUPPLY.DEVICE_ID and SUPPLY.COLOR_TYPE, I need the most recent ROW -> MAX(UNINSTALL_DATE)

Use `ROW_NUMBER` function in this way:

```
SELECT s.*,
       row_number() OVER (
             PARTITION BY DEVICE_ID, COLOR_TYPE
             ORDER BY UNINSTALL_DATE DESC
       ) As RN
FROM SUPPLY s
```

This query marks most recent rows with RN=1

---

> JOINED with more or less all the columns in DEVICE.

Just join the above query to DEVICE table

```
SELECT d.*, 
       x.COLOR_TYPE,
       x.SERIAL,
       x.UNINSTALL_DATE
FROM (
   SELECT s.*,
          row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY DEVICE_ID, COLOR_TYPE
                ORDER BY UNINSTALL_DATE DESC
          ) As RN
   FROM SUPPLY s
) x
JOIN DEVICE d
ON d.DEVICE_ID = x.DEVICE_ID AND x.RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - so you could group by `device_id, color_type` and `select max(uninstall_date)` as well, and join to the other table. But you would miss the `serial` value for the most recent row (for each combination of `device_id, color_type`).

There are a few ways to fix that. Your attempt with `rownum` was close, but the problem is that you need to order within each "group" (by `device_id, color_type`) and get the first row from each group. I am sure someone will post a solution along those lines, using either `row_number()` or `rank()` or perhaps the analytic version of `max(uninstall_date)`.

When you just need the "top" row from each group, you can use `keep (dense_rank first/last)` - which may be slightly more efficient - like so:

```
select   device_id, color_type, 
         max(serial) keep (dense_rank last order by uninstall_date) as serial, 
         max(uninstall_date) as uninstall_date
from     supply
group by device_id, color_type
;
```

and then join to the other table. NOTE: `dense_rank last` will pick up the row OR ROWS with the most recent (max) date for each group. If there are ties, that is more than one row; the `serial` will then be the max (in lexicographical order) among those rows with the most recent date. You can also select min, or add some order so you pick a specific one (you didn't discuss this possibility).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      d.ACCOUNT_CODE, d.DNS_HOST_NAME,d.IP_ADDRESS,d.MODEL_NAME,d.OVERRIDE_SERIAL_NUMBER,d.SERIAL_NUMBER,
      s.COLOR, s.SERIAL_NUMBER, s.UNINSTALL_TIME
FROM (
      SELECT s.DEVICE_ID, s.LAST_LEVEL_READ, s.SERIAL_NUMBER,TRUNC(s.UNINSTALL_TIME), row_number() 
OVER (
      PARTITION BY DEVICE_ID, COLOR
      ORDER BY UNINSTALL_TIME DESC
      ) As RN
FROM SUPPLY s 
WHERE s.UNINSTALL_TIME IS NOT NULL AND s.SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
        )

JOIN DEVICE d
ON d.ID = s.DEVICE_ID AND s.RN=1;
```

@krokodilko: thank you very much for your help. First query works. Modified it in order to remove junk, putting real columns name i need (yesterday evening i had no access to the DB) and getting only the data I need.

Unfortunately, when I join the two tables as you suggested I get error:

> ORA-00904: "S"."RN": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

If i remove s. before RN, the ORA-00904 moves back to s.DEVICE_ID.